# Issue with static variables in Java

Tags: java, variables, static, single-instance

I need an explanation for the output of the below code:

```
class Stats
{
    static int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    void printMe()
    {
        System.out.println(a+b);
    }
}

public class Static
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Stats s1 = new Stats();
        Stats s2 = new Stats();
        s1.b = 30;
        s1.printMe();
        s1.a = 20;
        s2.printMe();
    }
}
```

Output:
40
40

I expected it to be 40 and 50 as there should be only one copy of static variable 'a' which is modified by through reference 's1' to 20.

Comment: Static means affecting the entire class. There is only one `Stats.a` and only one `Stats.b`. It is therefore good practice to refer to static variables by class name instead of an instance name.

Comment: What you probably want are final variables.

Comment: @gangqinlaohu If you use Stats, I get 40 and 50 as output but static variable I believe should have only one copy.  So, even if I alter it using an object reference, that single copy must get modified?

Comment: The first (s1) is 30 + 10 and the second (s2) is 20 + 20. BTW, did you hear about a wonderful tool called debugger ?

Comment: Thanks, I got it now.

Comment: @alfasin yes the debugger can help but understanding the concept with an explanation is better.

Comment: @alfasin  A debugger, in cases like these, would only be an easier way of walking through code. I often don't use it, and just walk through my code in my head (because I'm to lazy to run it)

Comment: @gangqinlaohu and  Luiggi Mendoza: I also rarely use a debugger, but if I can't figure it out by walking through the code, I would definitely use one before posting this question. Voting to close as "too localized"

Comment: @alfasin I would say that it's a reasonable beginner Java question, but the OP probably should have searched the web for 'Java static variables' before asking the question.

Comment: @gangqinlaohu oh he KNOWS what static means: see the last two lines of the question :)

Comment: @gangqinlaohu - There are as many Stats.b copies as there are instances of Stats.  Only Stats.a is static.

Comment: The reason you get the second 40 is that you're adding the 20 from a and the 20 from b in the second instance of Stats, that second b never having been modified from its initial value of 20.

Answer (score 4):

`a` is static also called a "*Class Variable*", 
the value of `a` will be equal in all the instances of `Stats`,

so in the first call:
`a` is equals to 10 and `b` is equals to 30 for s1, 
so `a+b` is equals to 40,

and in the second call:
`a` is equals to 20 and `b` is equals to 20 for s2,
so `a+b` is equals to 40